# nhibernate entity multi mappings

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I have entity fluently mapped to existing oracle view:

```
public class MyEntityMap : ClassMap<MyEntity>
{
    public class MyEntityMap()
    {
        ReadOnly();
        SchemaAction.None();
        //mappings
    }
}
```

I'm querying oracle view for entities and filtering them based on certain criteria, let's say, where created_date more than 14 days. Those entities should be written into the database for future reporting use. For that purpose I've created a table which is exact clone of oracle view in terms of fields. And I'd like to map exactly the same MyEntity to my own table. Something like that:

```
public class MyHistoricalEntityMap : ClassMap<MyEntity>
{
    public class MyHistoricalEntityMap()
    {
        Table("HistoricalEntities");
        //mappings
    }
}
```

Also, I have a service responsible for querying view, but I want to add a method to store my historical entities, smth like below:

```
public class MyEntityService : IMyEntityService
{
    private IRepository<MyEntity> _repository;
    ...    
    public IEnumerable<MyEntity> GetEntities(){...}    
    public void StoreHistoricalEntities(IEnumerable<MyEntity> historicalEntities) {...}
}
```

So, question is: how do I specify, that I want to (or nhibernate should) use MyEntityMap for querying, but MyHistoricalEntityMap for storing results? Or what other solution can I apply?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use two different mappings for an entity.

What you *can* do is use [custom SQL for loading](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-load).

Comment: Basically, load my all entities using custom SQL loading, filter them as needed and then store using my service in my historical table? Thx